# Is there a term for the relationship between these two functions?

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a function $f(x)= \frac{x-2}{x^2-4}$ and another function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+2}$. These functions are identical at all points except for $x=2$. Is there a term to describe the relationship between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Comment: You can say $g$ is an extension of $f$.

Comment: Well $\Gamma_f \subset \Gamma_g$, that's something.

Comment: In particular I would call it an extension by continuity

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek Thanks. Also what does gamma mean in that?

Comment: It is established to say that $f$ has a removable singularity at $2$.  $g$ is the function with that singularity removed, but I don't know a term for the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: defining a function that fills in the holes in $f$ is known as [removing its discontinuity](http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage4/Lesson/removable.html). You could say that $g(x)$ is $f(x)$ with its discontinuity removed.

Say that $\overline{f}$ is the function $f$ with its discontinuities filled. Then

$$\overline{f}(x)=\lim_{u\to x} f(u)$$